# RegEx possible optimizations and shorthand tricks

Tags: javascript, regex

I attempted to create a RegEx that matched usernames with 1 to 20 characters and no more than one space (optional though). And by trial and error obtained this chunky RegEx:

```
[0-9A-Za-z]{3,20} ?[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20}
```

How can I optimize this RegEx to be shorter and generally better?

Comment: It looks like that could matches usernames up to 40 characters, for example "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead that says the input string cannot have two spaces:

```
^(?!\S* \S* )[0-9A-Za-z ]{1,20}$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wPoimc/1/)

Note: Your regex does not allow space in the first 3 positions, but this one does. I am going just by your verbal description, not your regex. (Your regex would also allow more than 20 characters in the name, as many as 41, and that's why I ignored it).

Comment: Holy crap thank you for the feedback, appreciated! Also how would it be without 3 spaces at the beginning?

Comment: @Thefourthbird How would that compare with `^(?!.*? .*? )[0-9A-Za-z ]{1,20}$`?

Comment: The answer has been updated per the suggestion made by @Thefourthbird

Comment: ++ Using `.*?` [lazy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy) causes backtracking, which you don't need in this case: